# Ogone payment gateway integration php

Tags: php, installation, config, payment, gateway

i have some problems to use ogone merchant service
1-when i try to make test payment with "Create a test payment with Ogone e-Commerce Merchant assistant option " ogone return empty result for $_POST content(did not return any parameter to my php result page)

2-when i want to connect with php post method to ogone server, some error occured:

The following error has occurred: unknown order/1/r/ & rec1 not included in your account

3- in the transfer to production mod process in the invoicing information ogone need to enter credit card details ,why i should enter credit card details as a merchant?

Comment: You probably better could contact Ogone with this. An order/1/r/ means the referer (the website where you come from) isn't allowed. Yours is probably not filled in in your Ogone account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ogone return empty result for $_POST content(did not return any parameter to my php result page)"
Check GET parameters - they don't seem to use post when redirecting back to merchant site.

As for errors, I have been receiving error "unknown order/1/r/" in case when SHA checksum of submitted parameters was incorrect, and "rec1 not included in your account" in case when 
I tried to submit alias name. I haven't yet figured out how to work with aliases, for now I simply removed all alias-related parameters from my submission to Ogone and it started to work.

As for point 3 - no idea what you're talking about. Never had to enter credit card information as a merchant.

UPD: Sorry, according to Ogone FAQ error code "unknown order/1/r" means that the referer has not been configured correctly in your technical account information. For incorrect SHA checksum it's "unknown order/1/s".

Comment: rec1 not included in your account : That means that you don't have enable the alias management in your ogone Options